# Getting exception org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No link found with text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make an application that will connect to [youtube-mp3.org](http://www.youtube-mp3.org). Normally on that site, we need to paste the youtube video url and click on **Convert Video** button. Then a Div with download link appears after conversion is done. All I need to send click command to the download link. I've written code for this which is as follows :

```
public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/");

    // Find the text input element by its id
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("youtube-url"));

    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE");

    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).submit();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();

    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

When I run this I get Exception which is:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No link found with text:  
    Download
    For documentation on this error,please visit:  http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
   Build info: version: '2.9.0', revision: '14289', time: '2011-10-20 21:53:56'
   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
   Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByLinkText(HtmlUnitDriver.java:650)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:235)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1221)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:974)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1218)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:394)
at com.general.Example.main(Example.java:38)
```

I'm pretty new to **Selenium**. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the link becomes clickable, after pressing the submit button.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Download")));
```